# Sheets Container Bound Script that Requires Authorization for other Users even when they are the Editor or Owner of file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a simple script in a Google Sheets doc that would generate a Google Document based on selected answers in the Google Sheets document. It refers to the document file and basically loads the info from the Google Sheets file into that Google Document. Then the generated Google Document is available in a G-drive folder where the user can access it. The script works great for me, but not for others. They get an authorization message as listed below. Note that I have given other users Editor access to the docfile and the docfolder (see below), and the Google Sheets itself. I even made them the owner of the Google Sheets, and it still has the same issue. I thought that I created a Container Bound script that would not need to be published. Any thoughts on how to fix this? Again, it works great for me, but not my colleagues who access it. Any assistance you can provide would be much appreciated!

Error Message:

> Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it.
> at GoogleDocCreator(GoogleDocCreator:4:30)

Script:

```
function GoogleDocCreator() { 

    const docfile = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    const docfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    const pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXX_XXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CompilerPage");
    const rows = currentSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 
    rows.forEach(function(row,index){
    if(index === 0)return;
 
    const copy = docfile.makeCopy(`${row[0]}, L&M Provisions`,docfolder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    body.replaceText("{ID}",row[0]);
    body.replaceText("{Section L}", row[1]);
    body.replaceText("{Section M}", row[2]);
    body.replaceText("{Characteristics}", row[3]);
    body.replaceText("{Errors}", row[4]);
    doc.saveAndClose();

})}
```

Comment: Do they have edit access to the container of the script?

Comment: How is the GoogleDocCreator function being called?

Comment: Have you given access to the pdf folder?

Comment: Yes, I made sure that they had edit access to the container and went so far as to make them the owner to see if that would work - no dice. I do have the script tied to an image that they click to create the Google Doc. (I assume that answers the question regarding how the GoogleDocCreator Function is being called(?). In relation to the PDFfolder, it does not exist yet. I started to add on a capability to convert the generated Google Doc to a PDF, but stalled out here. Thanks for any help you can provide to this beginner!!!!!

Comment: Solution came to light - Thanks to Ruben's comment! I deleted the PDFfolder code line (which was written to convert the Google Doc to PDF at a later date). I deleted that line and the script ran for the users. I assume this is because of the G drive authorizations to access folders. So (maybe) the script worked for me as author and owner of all folders (even the PDFfolder that did not exist), but for others to use the script, the script looked and saw no permissions for the user for that PDFFolder? Maybe? Anyhow great lesson learned here and thanks!